# deleting emails on both my laptop and iphone

Tags: macos, ios, email

I have an outlook exchange account that I use on my MacBook Pro and it is synched with my iPhone.  Until the newest update, when I delete a message on my laptop it also deleted it on my phone but recently it is only deleting on my computer!  Help . . . how do I get it to automatically delete both places?

Answer (score 1):

As long as *both* are st up as Exchange accounts (rather than POP or IMAP) both of these "views" should be looking at the account on the same server. Exchange is similar (if not based on) IMAP where all work is done on the server and only cached on the local device unless specifically downloaded.

What I would do is log into your OWA web interface (outlook web access) and see what shows up in the various mailboxes there. The web client doesn't cache significant data so that is a close to a live view of what is in your account. Look at both Outlook on your Mac and (presumably) the mail.app on your iPhone and see what is closest to the reality of the web interface.

Whichever seems to be the most wrong, delete the account on that device and re-add it. That will usually force a re-sync and bring both apps up to date with the server.

Note that I used to use the IOS mail.app for my Exchange (work) email until I discovered Microsoft's (free) Outlook client for IOS. I have been using that for the last year (give or take) and find it works a bit better than the built-in IOS mail.app when connecting to Microsoft Exchange servers.